# Skip test if dependency failed for particular parameter

Tags: pytest

Two tests.
First, check if file exists.
Second, when file exist, check if has any content.

3 files in total.

- file_0 exists and has content.
- file_1 not exist
- file_2 exists and is empty.

I want to skip second test for file_1 (do not see reason to check content, when file not exist) - how to do it?

Current code:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import pytest

file_0 = Path('C:\\file_0.txt')
file_1 = Path('C:\\file_1.txt')
file_2 = Path('C:\\file_2.txt')


@pytest.mark.parametrize('file_path', [file_0, file_1, file_2])
@pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_check_file_exists')
def test_file_exists(file_path):
    assert file_path.is_file(), "File does not exists."


@pytest.mark.parametrize('file_path', [file_0, file_1, file_2])
@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['test_check_file_exists'])
def test_file_has_any_data(file_path):
    assert os.path.getsize(file_path) > 0, "File is empty."
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that parametrized tests are not one, but several tests. To use `dependency` marks on parametrized tests, you have to make the dependency between specific parametrized tests, in your case from `test_file_has_any_data[file_0]` to `test_file_exists[file_0]` and so on.
This can be done by adding a dependency to each parameter:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_path", [
    pytest.param(file_0, marks=pytest.mark.dependency(name="f0")),
    pytest.param(file_1, marks=pytest.mark.dependency(name="f1")),
    pytest.param(file_2, marks=pytest.mark.dependency(name="f2"))
])
def test_file_exists(file_path):
    assert file_path.is_file(), "File does not exists."


@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_path", [
    pytest.param(file_0, marks=pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["f0"])),
    pytest.param(file_1, marks=pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["f1"])),
    pytest.param(file_2, marks=pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["f2"]))
])
def test_file_has_any_data(file_path):
    assert os.path.getsize(file_path) > 0, "File is empty."
```

`pytest.param` wraps a single parameter and allows to add marks specifically to that parameter, as can be seen.

This is also covered in the [pytest-dependency documentation](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#parametrized-tests).